# Read a string as an input using scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C language and I am trying read a character and a string (a sentence; max-length 25) from a user.

Not sure what I am doing wrong in the following lines of code, its giving me an error "Segment Fault".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char * str[25];
    char car;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    car = getchar();

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", &str);

    printf("\nThe sentence is %s, and the character is %s\n", str, car);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str` is an array of 25 pointers to `char`, not an array of `char`. So change its declaration to

```
char str[25];
```

And you cannot use `scanf` to read sentences--it stops reading at the first whitespace, so use `fgets` to read the sentence instead.

And in your last `printf`, you need the `%c` specifier to print characters, not `%s`. 
You also need to flush the standard input, because there is a `'\n'` remaining in `stdin`, so you need to throw those characters out.

The revised program is now

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void flush();
int main()
{
    char str[25], car;

    printf("Enter a character\n");
    car = getchar();

    flush();

    printf("Enter a sentence\n");
    fgets(str, 25, stdin);

    printf("\nThe sentence is %s, and the character is %c\n", str, car);

    return 0;
}
void flush()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I copy and pasted your code, but its terminating the program without letting me enter a sentence. So, right after I enter a character and press enter, before asking for a sentence input it gets terminated.

Comment: You would need to flush the standard input (don't use `fflush(stdin)`).

Comment: "_you cannot use `scanf` to read sentences--it stops reading at the first whitespace_" -- Actually, it is possible (by uaing the `%[` format specifier). `%s` in `scanf` stops reading on the first whitespace. BTW, `fgets` will read the `\n` left out by the `getchar()` in your program.

Comment: I am not using fflush(stdin), in fact I don't even know what that is lol, as I am new to c language. I think this my 3rd or 4th program I ever wrote in c.

Answer (score 13):

You have to make four changes:

1. Change

   ```
   char * str[25];
   ```

   to

   ```
   char str[25];
   ```

   as you want an array of 25 `char`s, not an array of 25 pointers to `char`.
2. Change

   ```
   char car;
   ```

   to

   ```
   int car;
   ```

   as `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.
3. Change

   ```
   scanf("%[^\n]s", &str);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf( "%24[^\n]", str);
   ```

   which tells `scanf` to

   1. Ignore all whitespace characters, if any.
   2. Scan a maximum of 24 characters (+1 for the Nul-terminator `'\0'`) or until a `\n` and store it in `str`.
4. Change

   ```
   printf("\nThe sentence is %s, and the character is %s\n", str, car);
   ```

   to

   ```
   printf("\nThe sentence is %s, and the character is %c\n", str, car);
   ```

   as the correct format specifier for a `char` is `%c`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

// This is minimal change to your code to work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char car,str[25];

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    car = getchar();

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    printf("\nThe sentence is %s, and the character is %c\n", str, car);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you answer old questions? Is there anything different from the pre-existing answers?