# Warning: Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char(*)[50]'

Tags: c

I don't know how to fix this warning, but especially why it appears in my code. In the first phase, my code has to record some names and surname and I used structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct STUDENT{
    char surname[50];
    char name[50];
} student;

int main()
{
    student a[30];
    int aux;
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Surname:");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].surname);
        printf("Name:");
        scanf("%s",&a[i].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`&a[i].surname` is actually giving the address of struct member array `surname`. `surname` is of type `char [50]` so it's address will be of type `char (*)[50]`. As an argument to a function, array decay to pointer to it's first element. So, `a[i].surname` will do the job. You need to remove `&` from the argument.

```
printf("Surname:");
scanf("%s",a[i].surname);
printf("Name:");
scanf("%s",a[i].name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `&` in strings as `surname` is already in format scanf is expecting it.

```
printf("Surname:");
scanf("%s",a[i].surname);
printf("Name:");
scanf("%s",a[i].name);
```

Also, please read why you have to set length for string in `scanf`.

[Read a string as an input using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103745/read-a-string-as-an-input-using-scanf)

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is looking for a pointer to `char`, but in your code you've got this

```
scanf("%s",&a[i].name);
```

`a[i].name` is an array of `char` which for the purposes of `scanf` is the same as a `char *`, but you're getting the pointer to it, so you end up with `char (*)[50]`. Just remove the unneeded ampersand and you'll remove the warning and fix your code.