# How to input a number of words as many as the given number?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int Number_of_words, lower_limit = 1;
    char word;

    printf ("Number of Words: ");
    scanf ("%d",&Number_of_words);

    for (lower_limit = 1; lower_limit <= Number_of_words; lower_limit += 1)
    {
        printf("Word: ");
        scanf("%str",&word);

    }
}
```

so, I want to make a code that will allow the user to input a number of words as many as the number that has been input by the user before. For example,when I run the code, if the input is "4" on "Number of Words", that will allow me to write 5 words. But instead of allowing me to write 4 words, it asks me to input more than 5 words.

[(image)It keeps asking more than 4 words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XclB8.png)

Comment: You should store them in an array and if you don't want to print "Word:" more than once, move it outside the loop

Comment: please only tag the language you are using. Your code is c++ not c.

Comment: `%s` requires a char array big enough to store all the input characters plus a terminating NUL. You have given it one `char` which results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: ...however, the only c++ is `using namespace std;` which you could safely remove. Is this supposed to be c++ or c?

Comment: Trying to read a C string into one char will not go well.  You need an array of char if you wish to read anything bigger than an empty string, ie. one NUL:(

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'm sorry, Im pretty new with C++. I watched some tutorials on youtube  and some of them write *using  name space std ;* .

Comment: @Ramesh How to store them in an array? Im sorry im pretty new with this language.

Comment: better read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and better learn from a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Most online tutorials are really bad. By the time you realize their mistakes you do not need them anymore, hence they arent really good for beginners

Comment: @TooGuilty Instead of us posting an answer a better thing would be if you start learning the basic data structures that'll surely clear up your doubts.

Comment: And when you learn C++, you should learn proper C++. With streams and standard containers. Your code is C. Also you should not follow tutorials that don't explain _why_ they do things. Like `using namespace std;`, which [is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). It's not some magic line of code that has to be there. Actually it serves no purpose at all here.

Comment: I would recommend to change the tag to C. There is no C++ in the shown example. I think this is a C Question-

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a string as an input using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103745/read-a-string-as-an-input-using-scanf)

Comment: @ArminMontigny Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%str",&word);` causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) since `word` is pointing to character, not a character array. Thus *anything* may happen.

Side note: `"%str"` should have been `"%s"`.

Here's how you can do it in C++:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::size_t sz;
  std::cout << "Number: ";
  std::cin >> sz;

  for (std::string s; sz-- && std::cin >> s; /*nothing*/) {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ayxan are there any specific differents between doing it in C and doing it in C++? I'm sorry I'm pretty new. I just started studying C for college (1st year) just a few days ago and the previous language that I learned was Python (which was much easier).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong format specifier for `scanf` in your code, c++ has `std::cout` and `std::cin` from `<iostream>` for formatted in/output. Next, a `char` holds a single character not a string. For strings there is `std::string`. Moreover, [`using namespace std;` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), it is better to declare variables only when you need them, and it is common convention to reserve capital starting letters for types or constants.

The corrected code could look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    size_t number_of_words;   
    std::cout << "Number of Words: ";
    std::cin >> number_of_words;

    for (size_t i=0;i<number_of_words;++i) {
        std::string word;
        std::cout << "word: ";
        std::cin >> word;
    }
}
```

If you want to actually store all the words for later use, you should use a `std::vector<std::string>` to store them.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any specific differents between doing it in C and doing it in C++?

Comment: @TooGuilty c and c++ really are two different languages. The code you posted looks like c (except the `using namespace std;`) and after fixing the errors it is also valid c++, but in general it is a myth that valid c is also valid c++. The thing is: I dont know C, so I cannot tell you how one would do it in c