# how to use only scanf("%s") to input print out strings with white space

Tags: arrays, c, string

how would you use only the  `scanf("%s",...)` not `scanf("%[^,]s")`,to take white space strings as input and also print it as an output with spaces

example:

```
input: hi my name is..
output: hi my name is..
```

I believe i would have to use malloc and realloc to constant resize the array but I'm still not sure how to put it all together

Comment: Do you mean to call `scanf` in a loop? You will miss spaces anyway, if there are more than one, for example. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes call scanf until EOF but i want to print out the strings with spaces, which means i probably have to string together multiple words together

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a string as an input using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103745/read-a-string-as-an-input-using-scanf)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `scanf`? Maybe it would be easier to accomplish what you want with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)? This function reads one line of input per function call and it discards nothing. It does not even discard the newline character at the end (but you can remove this yourself easily).

Comment: You would use a loop and then concatenate each string into a longer one, printing when the next character after the last string read was `'\n'` or `EOF` is returned. (this is not optimal, but doable -- you must also use the appropriate *field-widtih* modifier with `"%s"` -- otherwise it is no safer than `gets()`)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the maximum line length, you could use `fgets` for that. But to be more flexible, then yes, `malloc` and `realloc` is the way to go. Here is an example, just remember to `free` the string after use. You may also want to modify the error handling to your needs.

```
/* Return new string, or NULL on error*/
char *my_readline(FILE *f)
{
   /* empty string must at least have place for zero termination */
   char *str = malloc(1);
   if (!str)
      return NULL;
   
   /* Length of string, not including zero termination */
   size_t str_len = 0; 

   int ch;
   while ( (ch=fgetc(f)) != EOF )
   { 
       if (ch == '\n')
       {
          /* zero terminate string, and return */
          str[str_len] = 0;
          return str;
       }
       /* 
          increase buffer space for new character and zero termination

          We must use a temporary pointer, so that we still have access to the old
          pointer in case of error
       */
       char *tmp = realloc(str, str_len + 2);
       if (!tmp)
          {
             free(str);
             return NULL;
          }
       str = tmp;
       str[str_len] = ch;
       str_len++;
   }
   /*
      If we reach this line, there was en error reading the file, or the last
      line was not terminated by a newline. In any case we signal an error
   */
   free(str);
   return NULL;
}
```

Some people prefer to increase the buffer in larger steps to gain some efficiency. But if this function is not your bottleneck, the extra complexity is not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read words with `scanf` using the `"%s"`format specifier and concatenate them into a line using a loop (adding spaces where needed). You can use a fixed size buffer if you have some reasonable maximum number of characters you anticipate, or you can allocate and reallocate using `malloc` and `realloc` -- that is up to you. In either case the logic is the same, you have to track the number of characters available and how many you have used to know whether the next word will fit. The only difference being when dynamically allocating memory you have the option to reallocate additional storage and keep going, while in the case of the fixed buffer you simply have to handle the error of the line being too long to fit.

In either case when using `scanf` with the `"%s"` conversion specifier, you must also use the *field-width* modifier to ensure you don't read more characters than will fit into the storage for the word. For example if your word buffer is `128` characters, you must use `"%127s"` to limit the number of characters you can store to `127` plus `1` for the *nul-terminating* character. Otherwise your use of `scanf` is no safer than using `gets`, see [Why gets() is so dangerous it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)

A simple example addressing your input and output could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024   /* max chars per-word and line */

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC + 1] = "", word[MAXC];    /* line and word buffers */
    size_t remain = MAXC;                   /* available space that remains */
    
    fputs ("input : ", stdout);                     /* prompt for input */
    for (;;) {                                      /* loop continually */
        char c;                                     /* char following word */
        int rtn = scanf ("%1023s%c", word, &c);     /* read word & c, save return */
        if (rtn > 0) {                              /* if word read */
            size_t len = strlen(word);              /* get word length */
            if ((remain - len) > 0) {               /* if space remains */
                if (remain < MAXC) {                /* if not 1st word */
                    strcat (buf, " ");              /* add space between words */ 
                    remain--;                       /* decrement remains */
                }
                strcat (buf, word);                 /* add word to buf */
                remain -= len;                      /* reduce remain by len */
            }
            else {  /* handle line too long */
                fputs ("error: line too long.\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (rtn == EOF || c == '\n') {              /* if EOF or end of line */
            printf ("output: %s\n", buf);           /* output line */
            break;                                  /* break */
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/scanf_words_buf
input : hi my name is..
output: hi my name is..
```

The key is to put your accountants hat on and ensure you do not write beyond the storage available.

Answer (score 1):

> "How to use only `scanf(“%s”)` to input print out strings with white space?"

Short answer:

There is no way to do that. At least not with one call to `scanf()` on its own. The `%s` conversion specifier reads strings only up to the first white space.

You only can use the `[` format specifier to fetch strings with white space in it, when you want to explicitly use `scanf()` for that task, although `fgets()` would be probably more appropriate.

> "to input print out strings"

`scanf()` can't print out. It is input only.

Furthermore, The trailing *s* in `scanf("%[^,]s")` is redundant and might even cause some trouble. `%[` is not a suboperator of `%s`. It is a conversion specifier on its own.